# How to install multiple versions of MSBuild and use them with cmake

Tags: cmake, msbuild

I installed the MSBuild Tools with the current 2022 Installer, as seen in the image i also install MSVC 140, 141 and 142 as well as the c++ cmake-tools for windows.

[image: Visual Studio Installer]

Now, if i want to run cmake with a Generator other than "Visual Studio 17 2022" cmake is giving me the following error:

[image: CMake Error]

So, my question is, how do i install multiple versions of MSBuild which are actually usable by cmake?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have 2022 installed, so you can't use any other generator. You installed *toolkits* using Visual Studio 2022. You can define the toolkit using the command line, e.g.:

`cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -T v142`

See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared it up  coming from Linux, windows Infrastructure is still a mystery for me